# GKE Ingress cannot find service resource

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE Ingress, set up according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) tutorial. It worked great for a few weeks, till I wanted to add a new rule to the YAML configuration.

The following error is shown and no ingress is created anymore:

```
Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/<project_id>/zones/<zone>/networkEndpointGroups/<my-service>' was not found, notFound
```

I've simplified the yaml to only a single service, which still does not work anymore:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "web-static-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "cluster-certificate"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: webserver
      port:
        number: 3007
```

In the example above, no rules are defined, just the defaultBackend. Adding rules does not change the error; sometimes it only shows a different service. It also does not matter what service is used, all of the resources cannot be found.

However, the dashboard of the Ingress shows no errors about the services (all health-checks seem to pass):
[image: Dashboard that shows no errors]

I have been struggling for a while now, trying to use different services, use different rules, but I think I am missing something.

1. What system is responsible for this resource? The service itself seems to work fine and health-checks pass, so is it a mistake on the Ingress end?
2. When looking at the [LoadBalancer dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/loadbalancing), no LoadBalancers are created. Is this also because the Ingress failed to be created?

I am aware more information might be needed to help me, but I am not sure what to provide as it feels like I am searching in the dark. Please let me know!

**-Update-**

As can be seen below, the 'webserver' service looks good.
[image: Kubernetes Engine > Service & Ingress, shows healthy service]

I have deleted and re-created the Ingress multiple times, but this does not have an effect. `kubectl describe Ingress basic-ingress` shows the following:

```
Name:             basic-ingress
Namespace:        production
Address:          
Default backend:  webserver:3007 (10.6.128.139:3007)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     webserver:3007 (10.6.128.139:3007)
Annotations:  ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-065ca8b6-e85b-42ad-9113-6babe367a2d8
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
              kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web-static-ip
              networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: cluster-certificate
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----                   ----                     -------
  Normal   Sync    3m48s (x3 over 3m48s)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Warning  Sync    31s (x16 over 3m30s)   loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/<project_id>/zones/<zone>/networkEndpointGroups/<my-service>' was not found, notFound
```

`kubectl get ingress basic-ingress` shows:

```
NAME            CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
basic-ingress   <none>   *                 80      6m34s
```

In the Network Services menu/Backend Services, the following is shown:
[image: GCP->Network Services -> Backend Services]

All other tabs are empty (so no load balancer is seen). It says that the service is not in-use by anything (see picture above).

Comment: Are you able to see the service "webserver" on [Kubernetes Engine > Service & Ingress]? this could be related with the error showed

Comment: Can you post the result of `kubectl describe Ingress basic-ingress` ?

Comment: Also, have you tried deleting the Ingress resource and recreating it?

Comment: @NadiaEspinosa Yes, it looks correctly (I've added an image in the original post)

Comment: @GariSingh I've added the result of that command to the original post. I've recreated this Ingress multiple times already, does not seem to affect the results.

Comment: Did you are trying to implement a [Network Endpoint Group](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg) with this Load Balancing?

Comment: Can you try adding the annotation `cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": false}'` to your Ingress?

Comment: @GariSingh This did not seem to change the results, it still fails to find the resource and therefore fails to create the Ingress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not understand why this was broken, or why the following fixed it.

I simplified my Ingress to not have any annotations and applied that:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: webserver
      port:
        number: 3007
```

This resulted in a working Ingress! After this, I added the `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "cluster-certificate"` annotation, which still worked. Finally, I added the `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "web-static-ip"`.
My dev-website worked again.

Somehow, it looks like something went wrong and simply removing and re-applying did not fix it. Applying a very simple Ingress did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the gcp link below, it need's to be global static IP.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#use_an_ingress

> Use an Ingress
>
> If you choose to expose your application using an Ingress, which
> creates an HTTP(S) Load Balancer, you must reserve a global static IP
> address. Regional IP addresses do not work with Ingress.

```
gcloud compute addresses create global-static-ip --global
```